# Firefox 'cannot establish secure connection' to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have hosted a website using firebase hosting, but a handfull of customers complain their browser (I know one is mozilla) gives a message that it cannot establish a secure connection, and thus not loads the page.

It is this site:
https://mad-science-aanmeldingen.firebaseapp.com/zuid-holland

It uses a rewrite to /index.html so the URL is a bit different then the page that is loaded, but this seems to be a firebase feature.

Firebase hosting config:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "inschrijvingen",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
  }]
  }
}
```